# How to add custom dynamic urls to articles/posts etc in Node and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, routes

I want to have custom urls on my posts which would display something like "www.website.com/post_name" instead of "www.website.com/12312874112".
This is my routing

```
app.get("/:id" ,function(req, res){
Post.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundPost){
    if(err){
        res.redirect("/");
    } else {
        res.render("show", {post: foundPost});
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you not creating a new endpoint which reads the post_name

Comment: I don't really know what you mean, any documentation on that?